# How to change grey color of source code in a compiled source file?

Tags: java, netbeans

I use Netbeans 15 on Windows 10 x64, JDK 19.

[image]

for example, I see source

```java
    /**
     * Prints a double and then terminates the line.  This method behaves as
     * though it invokes {@link #print(double)} and then
     * {@link #println()}.
     *
     * @param x  The {@code double} to be printed.
     */
    public void println(double x) {
        if (getClass() == PrintStream.class) {
            writeln(String.valueOf(x));
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

How to change grey color of source code in a compiled source file?

[image]

Comment: This result from a quick search might help: https://devm.io/java/the-complete-guide-to-tuning-the-appearance-of-netbeans - Note that this question is more about tool configuration rather than an actual programming problem so it's probably not a good fit for SO. - Btw, your title mentions "compiled source file" but I can't see any _compiled_ file, just a normal source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see it with gray background because it is a readonly file.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Highlighting -> Readonly files` and change `Background` color to white.

Comment: I will try then feedback (NetBeans at my office) at Monday.

Comment: @JamesGrey Was it helpful in the end?

Comment: Helpful. I have been downloaded, and test your solution. It works.